# function inside style inside echo function

Tags: php, css, wordpress, function

I know this is possible but I just can't make it work. I know I am getting stuck with ""`s or ; or )

So, here is the code :

```
function my_login_head() { 
     echo "
    <style>
    body.login #login h1 a {"; 
    <?php echo
         "background: url("myfunction('image', get_template_directory_uri()                       ."/images/image.png");?> ") no-repeat scroll center top transparent; 
    height: 90px;
    width: 100px;
    }
    </style>
    "; ?>
```

I can't get the punctuation right. I just want to execute 'myfunction', and get the url atribute right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try This:

```
<?php
function my_login_head() {   
?>  
<style>  
body.login #login h1 a {
  background: url("<?php echo myfunction('image',get_template_directory_uri().'/images/image.png'); ?>") no-repeat scroll center top transparent; 
  height: 90px;
  width: 100px;
}
</style>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked! I thought of it this way but couldn't get the punctuation right

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
function my_login_head() 
{
    ?>  
    <style type="text/css">  
    #login h1 a {
      background: url("<?php echo myfunction('image',get_template_directory_uri().'/images/image.png'); ?>") no-repeat scroll center top transparent; 
      height: 90px;
      width: 100px;
    }
    </style>

<?php 
} 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function my_login_head() { 
     echo "
    <style>
    body.login #login h1 a {
        background: url(\"myfunction('image', " . get_template_directory_uri()   
        ."/images/image.png") . "\") no-repeat scroll center top transparent; 
    height: 90px;
    width: 100px;
    }
    </style>
    ";
```

Still it is quite spaghetti mess. Use templating

Answer (score 0):

```
function my_login_head() { 
     echo "
    <style>
    body.login #login h1 a {"; 
    echo "background: url(".myfunction('image', get_template_directory_uri()."/images/image.png").") no-repeat scroll center top transparent; 
    height: 90px;
    width: 100px;
    }
    </style>
    ";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php function my_login_head() { 
     echo "
    <style>
    body.login #login h1 a {"; 
     echo
         "background: url(";myfunction('image', get_template_directory_uri()."/images/image.png"); ") no-repeat scroll center top transparent; 
    height: 90px;
    width: 100px;"

    }
    echo "</style> "; }
    ?>
```